# How do link my './Projects' file to app.js in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Projects from './components/Projects';
import About from './components/About';

function App() {
  return(
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Home  />
        <Projects />
        <About/>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code in './Projects':

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function Projects() {
    return (
        <h1>Proj</h1>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

When I click the link for the Projects page the link doesn't display the content in function `Projects()`. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each component in a `<Route>` component. Something like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/route/to/projects">
    <Projects/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

There are a few different ways to do this with React Router. If you don't like the way I did it you can find more options here: [React Router Routes](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route)

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately its only Home that links that others don't ill have a look at the page you sent.

Comment: Nothing has changed only that Home links but About and Projects dont